# is there a ceil() alternative to turn 6523.70 to 6523 and not turn 6523.20

Tags: php

the function of ceil() in php is not useful in my case, because i want if the number contains from 0.50 to 0.99 then it's will ceil it, if it's smaller than 0.50 it's will not do anything.

example:

6523.70 will be 6524

but

6523.49 will stay same.

i hope you got it guys :)

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that `newceil(6523.49) = 6523.49` or `newceil(6523.49)=6523`?

Answer (score 9):

This will only change numbers which are >= .5

```
function weirdRounding($num) {
    if ($num - floor($num) >= .5) {
        return ceil($num);
    }
    return $num;
}

weirdRounding(6523.70) --> 6524
weirdRounding(6523.49) --> 6523.49
```

Answer (score 4):

Forgive me, I haven't written PHP in a while.

`if( ( $var - intval( $var ) ) >= 0.5 )
  $var = ceil( $var )`

Thus,

6523.70 to 6524 and
6523.49 stays 6523.49

Comment: That looks right, but I think you mean intval() (there is no int() function).